# How do I only allow a list a maximum number of items in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to apply a maximum number of items for a list, making sure that the code does not allow the function that appends to the list to add more than, for example, 3 items.

Function that appends to list:

```
    transactions = []

    def append_hash():
        transactions.append(hash)
```

How do I not allow `append_hash` to add more than three hashes to the list: `transactions` without deleting any previous hashes?

Comment: do you need a FIFO instead? or `deque` ?

Comment: You can use `if len(yourlist) > number`

Comment: The last condition implies attempts to append to the list should do something like raise an exception instead of pushing out an old element.

Comment: Maybe count the items in the list before appending.

Comment: where does `hash` come from - it is not provided to the function

Comment: @PatrickArtner given the global-scope modification of `transactions`, I'd assume `hash` is also globally-defined

Comment: Sorry about hash, it is also a globally defined variable. I did not include it in the question. It is just a randomly-generated hash for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

A `list` is, by definition, of arbitrary size. You'll need a new type instead.

```
class BoundedListFullError(RuntimeError):
    pass


class BoundedList:
    def __init__(self, max_size, x=None):
        if x is None:
            x = []
        self.values = []
        self.values.extend(x)
        self.max_size = max_size

    def append(self, x):
        if len(self.values) == self.max_size:
            raise BoundedListFullError(self.max_size)
        self.values.append(x)

    def extend(self, xs):
        if len(self.values) + len(xs) > self.max_size:
            raise BoundedListFullError(self.max_size)
        self.values.extend(xs)
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason that `BoundedListFullError` inherits from `RuntimeError`? I'm not too familiar with the conventions surrounding user-defined exceptions, just genuinely curious

Comment: `RuntimeError` is documented as "[r]aised when an error is detected that doesn’t fall in any of the other categories", and none of the other built-in exceptions seemed appropriate :)

Comment: The other choices would be extending `BaseException` or `Exception` directly; I think the former is easy to rule out, and there doesn't seem to be any compelling reason to choose `Exception` over `RuntimeError`.

Comment: I consult [the official list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) every time I define a custom exception, because I can rarely remember what would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could just subclass `list` and modify the `append` method:

```py
class MyStack(list):
    def __init__(self, max_size, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.max_size = max_size

    def append(self, value):
        if len(self) >= self.max_size:
            raise ValueError("NO!")
        # Per @chepner's suggestion
        super().append(value)

somestack = MyStack(3)
somestack.append(1)
somestack.append(2)
somestack.append(3)
somestack.append(4) # Raises ValueError
```

Comment: Why use `self.extend` instead of `super().append`? This could also be seen as a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), because it would never be true that `list.append` would raise an exception.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to look at a way around that. Thanks, I'll make that edit

Answer (score 0):

If you controll your code and ensure you only ever use your function:

```
transactions = []

def append_hash(h):
    transaction = (transactions + [h])[:3]
```

or

```
def append_hash(h):
    if len(transaction) < 3:
        transaction.append(3)
    # else:
    #    raise some error you need to choose/define
```

Neither of those will *enforce* it though - you can still modify the list without your function. You would need a seperate class - see [chepners answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55536318/7505395).

Adding a fourth hash will silently fail - if you want to raise an exception instead, the second solution can be adapted.